# NPM run serve is showing old state of my vuejs project on localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, localhost, vue-cli

npm run serve is showing an old state of my vue-cli project on localhost but not the actual one on the network address

I have tried to restart the npm run serve command but it didn't help

This is the output of the command

```sh
DONE  Compiled successfully in 46105ms                                                                                                                                    5:31:39 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://"network ip address":8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I expected it to show the current version of my vue project that I set up with vue cli but it's showing an old state of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Clear cache of your browser, try Chrome on incognito.

2 - Check where are the dist folder and if the code inside are updated (put console.log("testing") and search in the folder)

3 - Delete dist folder and run again `npm run build`

4 - Search the version in all the proyect to ensure where is the version get to show on web.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @MattChampion Can you please explain how this answer helped you? He seems to be referring specifically to `npm run build`, but your question (and the problem I'm having) is with `npm run serve`. How exactly did you resolve the problem?

Comment: Vote up if the answer help you :)

Comment: @Elezar The first point was really useful.